# GUI Automation testing framework for android games

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, android, gui

Is there any test framework which supports android games? I have used UiAutomator2.0 for GUI automation test, but for some games, it is unable to capture screen.

Answer (score 1):

GUI Automation for Android game I would suggest SeeTest Tool, You can use 30 days limited free [trial](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/seetest-automation/). Its having own Record and Play feature and Inbuilt UIAutomator for locating elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have listed out some of the Tools Which may useful to you.

- [Appium](http://appium.io/)
- [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/index.html)
- [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/)
- [Testdroid](https://cloud.testdroid.com/)
- [TestFairy](https://testfairy.com/)